# Fetch dependencies from hex.pm with Rebar3 for Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have added [poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison) library to rebar.config file:

```
{
  deps, [
    poison
  ]
}.
```

But when I run `rebar3 compile`, it shows me an error:

> ===> Package <<"poison">> not found. Fetching registry updates and trying again...
>
> ...
>
> ===> Package not found in registry: <<"poison">>.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Looks like `poison` does not support building from rebar3: https://hex.pm/packages/poison. `hackney` for example does: https://hex.pm/packages/hackney (see sidebar).

Comment: Seems like so, thanks. I have submitted an issue on Poison Github Issues page and now chose another library, jsx, which seems to work.